# Regex mismatch issue

Tags: c#, regex

I am having an issue with identifying a multiple character digit in a string.

What I am attempting to do is check, from right to left, for the first digits for comparison.

My original regex:

```
Regex.Match(s, @"\d{3}", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

This would match the first 3 digits it came across in any string. Eg:

- hello123 - Output: 123
- good234bye - Output: 234
- see-you-456-tomorrow - Output: 456

No worries. However, now we're not certain of the length the number might be, so we have changed the Regex to this:

```
Regex.Match(s, @"\d*", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

This looks for the first string of digits, any length, and uses that. *However*, it returns an empty match if the number is *not on the end of the string*. Eg:

- hello12 - Output: 12
- good-bye-1234 - Output: 1234
- see-1-you-2-morrow - Output: Nothing

How can I look for the first x-length of digits in a string, from right to left and disregarding any non-digit characters, without it returning an empty match?

Comment: have you tried tu use "Global" like so: Regex.Match(s, @"\d+g", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

Comment: I have not. What does that check for? (I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to regex)

Comment: I'm not sure of its syntaxe in C# but the g stand for global search

Comment: For general reference, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Quantifiers

A digit repeated once or more times

```
\d+
```

A digit repeated from 3 times to 5 times

```
\d{3,5}
```

A digit repeated at least 5 times

```
\d{5,}
```

---

You can read more about quantifiers in [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

---

As you may have realized,

```
              see-1-you-2-morrow
                                ^
                                |
\d* matches an empty position (here)
    between the last character and the end of string
```

Comment: You're saying "repeated"... to clarify do you mean "repeated" like "111"? or just *any* digit like "456"?

Comment: `\d+` is what you want.. The `+` repeats the regex construct. It will match "`456`"

Comment: The `\d+` gave me what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I'm new to Regex, but I guess it works for you!

```
 var s =    @"see-you-456-tomorrow";
            var r = Regex.Match(s, @"[[\d]]*\d*", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
            Console.WriteLine(r);
```

You can see it working [here](http://pei.to/cqst).

Comment: That regex means: `[[\d]` a digit or a "[" **+** `]*` a "]" repeated once or more times **+** `\d*` a digit once or more times. Test against the string "`see-you-456-tomorrow[`" to see the difference

Comment: The result will be 456, the first match (right to left). What you want the result to be Ben & @Mariano?

Comment: @ArthurCastro That's the expected result, yes. Nice job on the first try!